# IOS. segue.destinationViewController object is different from the Controller loaded

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm trying to make a transition between two ViewControllers using a Navigation Controller, the object referenced by segue.destinationViewController is: 0x1cd93590 (the next view), but when the change is made to the newly view this has a different number of object: 0x1cd4556d0. My code is:

```
- (void)updateCodeProduct:(NSString *)code {
    [session stopRunning];

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1111);

    // db acces.
    NSString *cadena = @"http://172.20.10.2/consultaProd.php?codigo=";
    cadena = [cadena stringByAppendingString:codigo];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:cadena];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *retorno = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    if (retorno == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@\n%@", url, [error localizedFailureReason]);
        return;
    }

    self.detailProd = nil;
    self.detailProd = [retorno componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailSegue" sender:self];    
}
```

The prepareForSegue method is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"%@", [segue destinationViewController]);

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController updateDetail:detailProd];
    }
}
```

The segue is performed, but the view does not reflect the current information, because is a different object.

Any Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the `updateDetail` method do? If it's trying to update a control in the destination controller, it's too early to do that, since the controls won't have been created yet. You just want to set properties (e.g. a `NSString` or whatever) in the destination controller. The destination controller should then take that property and update its controls in `viewDidLoad` of that destination controller.

In short, the address of the destination controller will be the same as address of the view controller itself. You don't show us your `NSLog` statements for those two addresses you're reporting, so it's impossible for us to say what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, the method -updateDetal belongs to DetailViewControler, and update two UILabels, quote(If it's trying to update a control in the destination controller, it's too early to do that, since the controls won't have been created yet). I correct this creating tho NSString and updating the labels in a -viewdidLoad method. And works fine.... Thanks a lot. :)